# Is there anything I can do while frozen by Mei?

Tags: overwatch

I know that nothing is possible with **Hanzo** and **Pharah** as I have played them against Mei and found out the hard way, but is there any hero that can escape from Mei after being frozen?

Comment: yeah, you can die.

Comment: In general, if you're already frozen, it's _way_ too late to be trying to counter Mei.

Comment: That's kind of her thing. Freeze -> punch in the face/giant mech suit/whatever. So the only counter is just staying away from her or killing her before you get completely frozen.

Comment: Prepare to get an ice spear through the head. That is about all you can do. (No you can''t really escape once frozen)

Comment: I always mash buttons. I don't think it unfreezes you quicker but it makes me feel better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you're frozen, you just have to hope someone else distracts her before she kills you. It is possible to be bubbled out by a friendly Zarya, but that's not under your control.

Anyone with an invulnerability (Reaper's Wraith Form, Zarya's bubble, Zenyatta's Transcendence) can still escape while being slowed, if they activate the ability before the full freeze takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge from beta there is nothing you can do to break free from her ice other than waiting or dying.

As of Today i did not find any changes in Patchnotes so i assume there is nothing else to do.